# Resize and Display image from server with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

Got a question.  I have images hosted on my server.  I already know of the method when an image is uploaded to resize it and save, but I have another thought in mind.

1. I was wondering if there is a way to resize when the image is requested from the user. Not when it was uploaded by the user.

So for example a user goes to upload an image and I DO NOT RESIZE it and save another copy of the resized image.  Instead, when the image is requested by the user via an ASP.NET img control/tag it would resize the image on the fly to display it and display it via the img tag/control.

Why would I want to do this?

To save on disk space.  Most servers have a disk space limit, but not a server processing limit.  So I would like to save on disk space and use the processing space instead.

**EDIT:** As a startup website its currently better that I save disk than saving processing time.  I don't have much money for large amount of space at this moment.  Hopefully it will change when the site launches.

Any ideas?  Thanks guys and girls.

Comment: Hi Scott, What possible scenario could make disk space more expensive than processing power? And would'nt the image resize (FOR EVERY USER REQUEST!) be very processing intensive and affect overall web app performance?

Comment: @Nahom: Not if it was combined with Amazon CloudFront caching or disk caching (or both). Dynamic image processing has endless advantages over pre-processing, the least of which is reduced disk usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you can 'control' the urls to the resized images, so for example the full-sized image might be referenced as `<img src="uploads/myphoto.jpg"/>` the thumbnail could be to an ASPX or ASHX like `<img src="uploads/myphoto.jpg.ashx"/>`?

This **[article on CodeProject - Dynamic Image Resize](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ImageResizeWithHttpModule.aspx)** seems to have exactly the source code you are looking for (and although it's in VB, it shouldn't be hard to port if you're a C# person). Hope that helps.

Finally, I'd encourage you consider the various forms of caching (both using Http-Headers, to ensure the images are cached at the client or proxy whenever possible; and using built-in ASP.NET features to avoid unnecessary processing of the same images over-and-over).

Although you'll be saving disk-quota, you're effectively slowing down every other page/request... just a thought.

Comment: It's better to use an HttpModule than an HttpHandler if you want to play nice with the URL authorization system. [Check out the list of image resizing pitfalls to avoid](http://imageeditor.codeplex.com/), or [grab the dynamic ImageResizer library](http://imageresizing.net) that avoids them all.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic image resizing has numerous advantages, the least of which is reduced disk space usage. However, it does need to be combined with a form of persistent caching, such as either Amazon CloudFront or a disk cache.

Dynamic image resizing gives you great agility on your web site, whereas pre-generating image variants locks you in, preventing the eventual changes you will have to make. When combined with caching, there is no run-time performance difference between the two.

The [ImageResizer library offers disk caching, CloudFront caching, and correct memory and cache management](http://imageresizing.net). It's been constantly improved and maintained since 2007, and is quite bulletproof. It's running a few social networking sites as well, some having over a million images.

It's a time-tested, traffic-tested, and unit-tested library :) It's also extremely simple to use - you just add `?width=x&height=y` to the query string. Functionality can be added via 20+ plugins, so you won't be weighed down by unused code and features.

The article mentioned by CraigD is inherently limited in its performance by the fact that it uses an HttpHandler instead of using an HttpModule - an HttpHandler cannot pass a request back to IIS native code for execution after the resized image is written to disk. It also doesn't adjust jpeg encoding properly or play well with the ASP.NET cache or URL authorization system. Although, I do have to admit - compared to most of the sample code I've seen, it [violates far fewer of the image resizing pitfalls I've compiled](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).

I strongly suggest [using the ImageResizer library](http://imageresizing.net). It's good code, I wrote it :) If you do end up using sample code or writing your own, [please avoid these pitfalls](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/)!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an implementation of IHttpHandler to respond to image requests, in that handler you can have code that loads the image from disk and transforms to it a size that is needed. You need to return the proper mime type with the response, and use the WriteBytes method (or something like it, I forgot the name). Also, you may look into content expiration headers, so that the image may not have to be loaded every time by the same client, but is instead cached.

Answer (score 0):

You claim unlimited processing but limited disk space. Most of the time, even if they don't enforce a processing limit, as you have more customers, hits to your site, processing will be a worse bottleneck than storage space, and it will cost more to add more processing. Furthermore,

- If you have large images, resized and compressed versions will occupy %10 of the space of the originals, even if you store a display and thumbnail version.
- Else, just serve them and display them resized by browser, it will be faster.

Answer (score -2):

It is not really actual resize of image, it is rather resize when you display an image, but i used with success just simple

```
 <img src="myimage" height="height you want to give" width="width you want
 to give" alt="" />
```

It is working every time.

Comment: the problem with this is that the image if over a megabyte stays a mega byte. C# resizes the image so it doesn't actually stay a megabyte

Comment: True , it is just for the display, the actual image size stay same.

Comment: This is ok for very small images (a few KB's) but not recommended for larger images for the aforementioned reasons. Server side resizing, and depending on throughput caching, is a better choice.